# what's the VScode shortcut for breaking words of a Horizontal line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

is there a shortcut of vscode editor to turn line from horizental to vertical ,convert this :

```
<View style={{flex:1,marginTop:20, paddingHoizental : 20, backgroundColor : '#FFF'}}>
```

into this

```
<View 
style={{flex:1,
marginTop:20, 
paddingHoizental : 20,
backgroundColor : '#FFF'}}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the first comma.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> several times to select all commas.
- Press <kbd>➔</kbd> to unselect the commas, and put a cursor after each one.
- Finally, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This results in:

```
<View 
style={{flex:1,
marginTop:20,
 paddingHoizental : 20,
 backgroundColor : '#FFF'}}>
```

If you didn't have inconsistent spaces after commas, it would align properly. Then you could select both the comma and the following space (if any).